# I keep getting the error message "subscript out of range",

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi

when I compare a table and a dump text file. I would load a powerbi to get a text file and then compareit with my already created table, so as to displaye the matching onesThis is the code that I ve been using to  load the dump and compare it with the already created table

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="dump", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""xx:\location.txt""),[Delimiter=""#(tab)"", Columns=17, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""market"", Int64.Type}, {""category"", Int64.Type}, {""brand"", type text},{""brand status"", type text}, {""vendor_code"", type text}, {""status_last_update_date"", Int64.Type}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Changed Type"", each ([brand status] <> """" and [brand_status] <> ""Audit"" and [brand status] <> ""SUPPRESSED""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "  " & _

    Workbooks("Sheet2").Connections.Add2 "Query - dump", _
        "Connection to the 'dump' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""us dump"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , "SELECT * FROM [us dump]", 2
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table1", Formula:= _
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else might be wrong with your code, but what you've posted won't even compile. You can't end a line with `_` unless you intend the following line to be a continuation of the current line. For example, your final line makes no sense without the next line. Your second line will also cause an error because of the `_`. Also, please format your code. Break up those long lines of text. It's hard for us to help you debug your code when one of the lines is 800+ characters long. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are your sure the workbook you are referring to is genuinely called "Sheet2"? (`Workbooks("Sheet2")`)